# Iterating an equation

Tags: python, loops

```
o_i = o_f(l, 1, f_1)
print(o_i)
o_i = o_f(l, o_i, f_1)
print(o_i)
o_i = o_f(l, o_i, f_1)
print(o_i)
o_i = o_f(l, o_i, f_1)
print(o_i)
o_i = o_f(l, o_i, f_1)
print(o_i)
```

I have tried

```
while (f_1 == 10):
    o_i = o_f(l, o_i, f_1)
    print(o_f)
```

among other codes.
Is there a way to create a loop for this series without having to keep on typing or copying and pasting for a long time? I have been trying to use a conventional (`for` or `while`) loop to address the issue, but I do not know how to use any of them to actually iterate a set of equations that does not have an unordered/ordered list as a variable. Also, is there a way to retain the solutions as a one dimensional array?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. Is there a limit or do you really want to continue indefinitely?

Comment: just put apart the first call, and do a classic simple loop for all the others which are identical

Comment: @quamrana I was typing in frustration so I said something stupid. There is a limit, but I am sure that it may take a while to get to up to 10000 results. I will append to ensure that it is not confusing.

Comment: Ok, if there is a limit, does the answer from @RandomDavis help?

Comment: Yes, the answer from @RandomDavis helps a lot! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, then you might be able to up-vote and accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is with a loop, and a 1D list storing the results:

```
o_i = 1  # initial value
num_loops = 10  # or however many loop iterations you want
results = []  # the list that stores the results
for _ in range(num_loops):
    o_i = o_f(l, o_i, f_1)
    results.append(o_i)
    print(o_i)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!